# Return nodes of a connected node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For a given node n, I want to get its related nodes *and* all nodes connected to the related nodes.
For example:

```
MATCH (n)-[:IN]->(x)
WHERE n.myid='myid'
RETURN n, x
```

How do I return all the x's connected nodes as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want type(r) to be `IN`,
Have you tried?

```
MATCH (n)-[:IN]->(x)-[]-(y)
WHERE n.myid='myid'
AND y<>n
RETURN n,x,collect(y)
```

I have it collecting y because you will otherwise get a bunch of "rows" for each, but that is totally up to you.

Try playing on:
http://console.neo4j.org

Console with above example
http://console.neo4j.org/r/yaczrx

Also, you may want to look into how deep you want that second lookup to go.

BTW: if you want to see the path in the console (you can see how the nodes are interconnected): http://console.neo4j.org/r/39mz9a

```
MATCH path =(n:Crew)-[:KNOWS]-m-[rr]-(x) 
WHERE n.name='Neo' AND x<>n 
RETURN n AS Initial_Node, m AS Linking_Node, 
collect(x) AS Nodes_connected_to_Linking_Node, path
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (n)-[:IN]->(x)--(y)
WHERE n.myid='myid'
RETURN n, x,y
```